# Laravel 8 use same form for edit and create ,

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to use the same form fields for Update and create,
using @include I load same form to create and update views,can someone explain why this is,,and what I am missing is,

feilds.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group pad-top40">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
            Warehouse Number
        </label>
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
            Number
        </label>
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
            Warehouse Code
        </label>
    </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i
                                    class="livicon" data-name="number"
                                    data-size="18" data-c="#000"
                                    data-hc="#000" data-loop="true"></i></span>
                    </span>
                <input type="number" class="form-control"
                placeholder="No" id="no" name="no">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i
                                    class="livicon" data-name="number"
                                    data-size="18" data-c="#000"
                                    data-hc="#000" data-loop="true"></i></span>
                    </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Warehouse Code" id="wh_code" name="wh_code" value='{{old('wh_code','')}}'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       <br>
       <br>

    <div class="row">
        <label for="address1" class="col-sm-8 control-label">
            Address Line 1
        </label>
        <label for="inputexpdate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
            Register Date
        </label>
        
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i
                                    class="livicon" data-name="address"
                                    data-size="18" data-c="#000"
                                    data-hc="#000" data-loop="true"></i></span>
                    </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" id="address1" name="address1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-append">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i
                                    class="livicon" data-name="number"
                                    data-size="18" data-c="#000"
                                    data-hc="#000" data-loop="true"></i></span>
                    </span>
                <input type="date" class="form-control"
                placeholder="dd/yy/mm" id="reg_date" name="reg_date">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

edit.blade.php

```
 <div class="card-body">
                {!! Form::model($warehouse, ['route' => ['admin.warehouses.update', collect($warehouse)->first() ], 'method' => 'patch']) !!}
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                @include('admin.warehouses.fields')

                {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
```

create.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.warehouses.store']) !!}
            {{ csrf_field() }}
                @include('admin.warehouses.fields')

            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
```

I have tried using {{old()}} but it won't load, the form fields are the same as the tables.
when I use the same with laravel collective,it work perfectly fine.

```
{!! Form::number('wh_no', null, ['class' => 'form-control','class'=>'livicon','data-name'=>'user']) !!}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate which type of issue you are facing? I did not get an idea from your question.

Comment: @RBC I want to use the same form for creating and updating, I have a lot of databases tables to connect to,, therefore i like to use the same form both function without using 2 views for create and Edit,
thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just use [->updateOrCreate()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts) with just 1 form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the object of the value to show the value on database. Let me show you every step:

```
public function create(){
  $warehouse = new Warehouse();
  return view('admin.warehouses.create', compact('warehouse'));
}
public function edit($id){
  $warehouse = Warehouse::findOrFail($id);
  return view('admin.warehouses.edit', compact('warehouse'));
}
```

Since, we have passed the `$warehouse` On both `create.blade.php` and `edit.blade.php` now we can use this same on both cases.

Now, on form, you have to use a value like this `$warehouse->fieldName`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email', $warehouse->email) }}">
```

If you want to use old values as well, you can use `old(fieldName,$warehouse->fieldName)`

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, this I have tried and it works, but I used the <input > type form just because I couldn't load liviicon or any other customization into the form, 
if I use <input type="text" I can load those but not the old value of edit form,

Comment: @maxasela I have updated my answer to input style, this should work.