# Laravel 8: using the same form for create & edit (not inserting some data)

Tags: php, laravel

Possible duplicates: 
[Laravel 8 use same form for edit and create ,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72785650/laravel-8-use-same-form-for-edit-and-create) 
[Laravel use same form for create and edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844022/laravel-use-same-form-for-create-and-edit)

I refactored and simplified the controller by following this [guide](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers)

The form works with insert and edit but some data aren't being sent to `DB` such as:

`ZoneNumber, ClaimingDate, receivedDate, lostItem`

I don't see any typos and can't find anything that prevents from saving these data.

I made sure the form renders based on condition:

```
@if($$lostFound->exists)
            <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.update', $lostFound) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @method('put')
        @else
            <form id="LostFoundForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @endif
            @csrf
```

And I also have the `old()` helper in the blade like so:

```
<div class="form-floating mb-10">
   <input type="text" min="0" class="form-control @error('lostItem') is-invalid @enderror" name="lostItem" placeholder="lostItem" value="{{ old('lostItem', $lostFound->lostItem) }}">
   <label for="lostItem">Item Name</label>
</div>
```

My controller looks fine...I don't see any issues here?

```
 public function create()
    {
        return $this->edit(new LostFound());
    }

    public function store(LostFoundRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->update($request, new LostFound());
    }

    public function edit(LostFound $lostFound)
    {
        $locationList = Locations::all();
        return view('pages.dataEntry.lostFound._addForm', compact('lostFound', 'locationList'));
    }

    public function update(LostFoundRequest $request, LostFound $lostFound)
    {
        $request->persist($lostFound);
        return redirect(route('data-entry.lost-and-found.index'))->with('success', 'LF updated successfully.');
    }
```

The `persists()` function is for saving the data:

```
public function persist(LostFound $lostFound)
    {
        // TODO: See if this can be refactored more.
        return LostFound::create( $this->validated() )
            ->addMedia($this->LFImage)
            ->toMediaCollection('lost-Items');

        $this->save();
    }
```

Comment: a few things I noticed. @if($$lostFound->exists), this could be a typo. $$lostFound does not look right. also, what are the data columns set in the model LostFound? some data not going to database implies two things. a) the columns are not set in the model. or b) the data types are not suitable (such as trying to input a variable into an int column).

Comment: Please check your model and fillable array. if ZoneNumber, ClaimingDate, receivedDate, lostItem are not added.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Mash tan and EHF Shahab said in the comments. `ZoneNumber, ClaimingDate, receivedDate, lostItem` are not added in the validation array